# how to change server time to client time on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So my end goal is to have Heroku server's Time.now to be same as the time that you do new Date.now() from JavaScript. What I have done so far is catching the timezone offset from JavaScript, and set Time.zone on Rails with the appropriate client timezone, so now, Time.zone is the right time zone. But however, Time.now is still reflecting the real timezone instead of the one feeding into Time.zone. I guess that's not what I suppose to do at the first place.

So once again, all I want is, the server time to reflect the client time, so any operations such as Time.now or DateTime.now or Date.today will be shown with the client time.

Comment: What if you have two users from two different continents at the same time?

Comment: i believe they will have different instances of the application with different time data.

Comment: Wrong; they will get two threads.

Comment: ok, but how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 5):

You should apply the UTC offset when *displaying* the times.

All server-side time calculation or storage should be done in UTC.

Comment: Sorry; I don't know Ruby very well.  Basically, add the requisite number of hours whenever you display a time.

Answer (score 5):

Check this

```
1.8.7 :001 > Time.zone
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0xb740d1b8 @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @utc_offset=nil, @name="UTC", @current_period=nil> 
1.8.7 :002 > Time.now
 => Fri Apr 20 13:13:53 +0530 2012 
1.8.7 :003 > Time.zone.now
 => Fri, 20 Apr 2012 07:43:59 UTC +00:00 
1.8.7 :004 > Time.zone = "Helsinki"
 => "Helsinki" 
1.8.7 :005 > Time.zone
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0xb70ab830 @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Europe/Helsinki>, @utc_offset=nil, @name="Helsinki", @current_period=nil> 
1.8.7 :006 > Time.now
 => Fri Apr 20 13:14:48 +0530 2012 
1.8.7 :007 > Time.zone.now
 => Fri, 20 Apr 2012 10:45:10 EEST +03:00 
1.8.7 :008 > Time.zone.now.to_time.strftime("%c").to_datetime
 => Fri, 20 Apr 2012 10:47:01 +0000 
1.8.7 :009 >
```

So `Time.zone.now.to_time.strftime("%c").to_datetime` will give you current time in user's timezone as UTC

[Time.now](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/now/class) always gives time in your server's timezone. [Time.zone.now](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-now) gives time in specified timezone.

Thanks,
Amit Patel